# JQuery AJAX POST call take long time

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I make a request POST with a huge data, but the SEND of  request take very long time. I said only send cause I've got this code :

```
 console.time('post load');
var req= new Array;
                req = { 
                     'data' :   $('input[name="data"]', $('#id_contain')) .serialize()
                };

var request = $.ajax({
                                    url : '/url',
                                    type : "POST",
                                     data : req,
                                    cache : false,
                timeout: 10000,
                                    dataType : 'json',
                                    async:   false,
                                    success : function(response){
                               alert('yes');
                }, 
                                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus,
                                            errorThrown) {
                                    //  if (debug_js) {
                                            console.log(jqXHR);
                                //      }
                                    }
                                });
               console.timeEnd('post load');
  console.log('data');
```

so according to this code, my request (post load) take like 25 seconds and I'v got timeout onajax request of 10sec.So I think it's only the jquery making request take time?
But if I change data the huge data with a simple string it takes like 0.01sec... So it's really due to my huge data?

Comment: Probably is how you handle the data in the back-end? How do you do this?

Comment: How huges is your data? How many bytes?

Comment: @pete don't know how many bytes but its like a string with 2401727 characters.

Comment: @Niels if it was php, the timout of ajax jquery will be trigger I think and if I make a return at the begining of callback php it's the same. I handle with $_POST

Comment: When using async: false javascript execution will stop until your post returns,

Answer (score 7):

Had the exact same problem. In one use-case I had to send 3 JSON Objects with all together ~20MB; and although only sending to localhost it took about 20 seconds or the browser timed out (Firefox, Chrome).

After a lot of try and error (also tried commenting out all server-logic, but didn't speed up the process) I finally found a solution:

1. Stringify your JSON-Data: JSON.stringify(req);
2. Add contentType: 'application/json' to your ajax request
3. On the Server-side add logic to read json content out of a http-post

The 3. step depends on what kind of server you are running. For me it is a node express server with body-parser module for the json-content.

After these changes the http-post creation of jquery went down from 20secs to something under 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

As Niels mentiond, it could be a backend (server side) issue. I suggest you first try commenting out any processing logic in the server side and immediately return your success condition.
If the request still takes long, then it's definitely the huge data that's the culprit and you may have to consider some sort of client side data-compression.
There is some analysis done [here](http://problemsolverblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/javascript-compression-libraries.html) on various options to do this.